# Useless rule due to conflicts in YACC

Tags: bison, yacc

The error message:

```
bison -vdy tjc.y
conflicts: 2 shift/reduce
tjc.y:72.26-29: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: return_type: type
```

EDIT 2: Further reduced the grammar to only the following rules. Same error due to same conflict. If I remove field_decl in the rules then the conflict goes away.

```
member_decl:      field_decl |  method_decl;

field_decl: STATIC type IDENT EQ SEMI;

method_decl:      STATIC return_type IDENT LPAR RPAR;

type:             INT | FLOAT;

return_type:      type | VOID;
```

Here's the section with the shift/reduce conflict in y.output:

```
state 18

7 field_decl: STATIC type . IDENT EQ SEMI
14 return_type: type .

IDENT  shift, and go to state 23

IDENT  [reduce using rule 14 (return_type)]
```

Please help me see what's going wrong here.

Comment: Is it possible that you're not mentioning that a type can be an ident as well? Is this really your (unedited) grammar?

Comment: I added a rule for type->IDENT and it produced more conflicts. And yes it is a part of the unedited grammar. This is a very simplified parser.

Comment: Could you manage to reduce this to the smallest grammar that displays the same error message?

Comment: Yes, please see the edit. Same error.

Comment: Try reducing it further. Does the error remain if you remove the last three forms of method_decl? can you remove the field_decl rule and its referents etc? We're trying to get to the smallest grammar that exhibits the error.

Comment: I reduced it again. Removing field_decl and its references results in no error.

Comment: But the current reduction still errors, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Perry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161293/perry)'s [analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474898/useless-rule-due-to-conflicts-in-yacc/9475240#9475240) of why you have problems is correct.

I was able to get similar warnings with this complete grammar (identical to yours, but with `%token` rules in place so I can compile it):

```
%token STATIC IDENT FLOAT INT VOID LPAR RPAR EQ SEMI

%%
member_decl:    field_decl |  method_decl;
field_decl:     STATIC type IDENT EQ SEMI;
method_decl:    STATIC return_type IDENT LPAR RPAR;
type:           INT | FLOAT;
return_type:    type | VOID;
%%
```

Given the analysis, the way I would probably fix it is this:

```
%token STATIC IDENT FLOAT INT VOID LPAR RPAR EQ SEMI

%%
member_decl:    field_decl |  method_decl;
field_decl:     STATIC type IDENT EQ SEMI;
method_decl:    STATIC type IDENT LPAR RPAR;
type:           INT | FLOAT | VOID;
%%
```

This compiles without any error in Bison.  You just need to add a semantic check in the processing for `field_decl` that ensures that the relevant `type` (`$2`) is not `VOID`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so the problem would appear to be this: you're generating an LALR(1) parser. With a lookahead of one, you can't distinguish the field_decl and method_decl rules. Why? Because both look identical since at first glance the parser can't distinguish a return_type from a type (both might contain INT or FLOAT). I'm not 100% sure as my memory of the distinctions between LR, LALR, etc. are all fuzzy right now, but it would appear that this is the problem -- that is especially indicated by the fact that when you tried removing field_decl the error vanished.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Any suggestion on how I would fix this while maintaining the same grammar?